# Dirac's equation, boosts and rotations

Tags: special-relativity, conventions, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-equation

If we consider Dirac's equation in two different frames of reference $$\left(i\gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}-m c\right) \psi(x)=0,$$ $$\left(i\gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}^{\prime}-m c\right) \psi^{\prime}\left(x^{\prime}\right)=0,$$ $S$ should be the matrix such that $$\psi^{\prime}\left(x^{\prime}\right)=\psi^{\prime}(a x)=S(a) \psi(x)=S(a) \psi\left(a^{-1} x^{\prime}\right),$$ and it should depend only on relative speeds and/or rotations between referentials $O$ and $O'$.

So if we have a generic $S=e^{-\frac{i}{4} \sigma_{\mu v} \omega^{\mu v}}$, we should have two distinct cases $S_L$ exclusively for the case of Lorentz transformations, and $S_R$ exclusively for the case of rotations. Note that both $\sigma_{\mu\nu}$ and $\omega^{\mu\nu}$ are $\textit{anti}$-symmetric, and $\sigma_{\mu\nu}$ is the commutator $\sigma_{\mu\nu} = \frac{i}{2}[\gamma_{\mu},\gamma_{\nu}]$.

For the case of boosts alone, one of the indices has to be zero. In this case $$\sigma_{0,i} = \frac{i}{2}[\gamma_0,\gamma_i] = i\gamma_0\gamma_i = i\alpha_i.$$
Now, if we develop $S$ in order for it to be $S_L$, i.e., have one index be zero, we get, $$S_L = e^{-\frac{i}{4}(\sigma_{01}\omega^{01} + \sigma_{02}\omega^{02} + \sigma_{03}\omega^{03} + \sigma_{10}\omega^{10} + \sigma_{20}\omega^{20} + \sigma_{30}\omega^{30})},$$ which, because of anti-symmetry, is just $$e^{-\frac{i}{2}(\sigma_{01}\omega^{01} + \sigma_{02}\omega^{02} + \sigma_{03}\omega^{03})} = e^{-\frac{i}{2}\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{\omega}} = e^{\frac{1}{2}\vec{\alpha}\cdot\vec{\omega}}.$$

I am, however, supposed to prove that $S_{L}=e^{-\frac{1}{2} \vec{\omega} \cdot \vec{\alpha}}$. How do I do this?. Do I have to calculate a commutator or anything of that sort? Or have I made a mistake  anywhere in this calculation? I am also not entirely sure what $\omega^{\mu\nu}$ is, since it is defined as such in an infinitesimal transformation: $a^{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}+\omega^{\mu\nu}+\cdots$.

Comment: It looks like you have to show the anticommutator between alpha and omega vanishes. You could try by reducing the expressions to use the anticommutator of Dirac matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help, but I am only familiar with a simpler argument.

The Dirac gamma matrices are not a vector, and do not define a direction in space, but they have properties under Lorentz transform which enable them to be treated as vectors. Specifically, if $f$ is a Dirac spinor, then $\gamma^a f$ transforms as a vector multiplied by a Dirac spinor. This is because, under a Lorentz transform, $k^{m'}_a$, the transformed gamma matrices also obey the defining relations, $$\{k^{m'}_a\gamma^a, k^{n'}_b\gamma^b\} = k^{m'}_ak^{n'}_b\{\gamma^a, \gamma^b\} = 2k^{m'}_ak^{n'}_b g^{ab} = 2g^{m'n'}  .$$ Thus, the transformed gamma matrices are simply another representation of the
gamma matrices. Since the representation has no meaning, the Dirac equation is
covariant (alternatively, we may regard this as a proof from covariance that the
specific representation is meaningless).